# RxJava chaine of consecutive operations

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I am a newbie in RxJava. I want to combine three consecutive asynchronous operations in to chain by RxJava2:

1. `fun getDataFromRESTApi(): Observable<TheData>`
2. `saveDataToCache(theData: TheData): Completable`
3. `getDataFromCache(): Observable<TheData>`

How can I do this? What rxjava methods I could to use?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you trying to achieve exactly but there's the `concatMap` operator :

```
getDataFromRESTApi()
  .concatMap(theData -> saveDataToCache(theData).toObservable())
  .concatMap(cachedData -> getDataFromCache()) //maybe not needed
```

In the other hand if `saveDataToCache` returns the saved data (cached) you don't need the third line.

Comment: Does this handle the situation where each API call is dependent on getting a 200 status code from the previous?

Comment: IMO handling API call must be inside `getDataFromRESTApi` method.